# Why we need (HEX | OCT)_to_DEC methods at all?

Tags: java, hex, literals, octal, radix

This might be a dumb question.

When i was trying to build some methods like *"octal to decimal efficiently"*, i was reminded that there are literals to do the job. That would be the fastest, bitwise, built-in in the system's way.

For octal, prefix with '0'.

For hexadecimal, prefix with '0x'.

ref: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Literals

```
for (int i=10; i<18; i++)
    System.out.println("Octal: " + ( 0 prefix i ));
```

Of course i know the word `prefix` doesn't work. Of course i know that notation is for *literals*. But if we can actually `prefix` it, and let the system to do the native conversion. Isn't it must be the **most efficient**?

And also, why can't? (Literals are literals, as the JLS says so, are not acceptable answers.)

Answer (score 4):

Because literals are evaluated at compile time. You want to evaluate run-time.

In Java, you can always use the `toString` method to display your value in any other radix than 10. In your case:

```
for (int i=10; i<18; i++)
    System.out.println("Octal: " + Integer.toString(i, 8));
```

Output: 12, 13, ....

Or, if you want to iterate over octal numbers, just put them there:

```
for (int i=010; i<018; i++)
    System.out.println("Octal: " + Integer.toString(i, 8));
```

Output: 10, 11, ....

Comment: Nice answer. So it might not be _most efficient_ at all? Could we know how the system does that?

Comment: The compiler will read the `0` and `0x` prefixed values and normalised values in the bytecode. There is no efficiency involved here, they are literals.

Comment: That `Integer.toString()` or `String.format()` are decimal to other radix. How about (hex | oct) to decimal?

Comment: @midnite where would that hex/oct number come from ? In your case, if you wanted to show `010` (octal 10), just put those numbers in your `for` statement: `for (int i=010; i<018; i++)`. Numbers have **values**, and their representation do not influence that.

Comment: i mean, is there a built in method which can do `oct2dec(10) = 8`? And of course for `oct2dec(18)` will throw some exceptions, or return specific value (such as -1) to indicate invalid.

Comment: There would be nothing to do for that method. `010` === `8`. It's the **exact** same number, but in a different notation. If your `oct2dec` method would take strings, it would be a different question; and that already exists in Java: `parseInt`.

Comment: What "the system" (the compiler) actually does at compile time is just invoke the normal method Integer.decode.  The compiler is a perfectly normal Java program and doesn't have anything magical in it.  Calling the normal decode, parseInt, to string, etc methods is the most efficient way to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Literals only facilitate you to write decimal, hex, octal etc in source code. They are still converted to primitives at compile.

For Conversion you'll need some String utility like [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).